# How to access the Rails application configuration data with string interpolation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have my third-party credentials set in the config/application.rb like a key, UUID, and other values.

```
config.username = "username"
config.uuid = "uuid"
config.yyy = "yyy"
```

For fetching them, I have to write multiple lines to fetch the data which is

> Rails.application.config.key

> Rails.application.config.UUID

> Rails.application.config.yyy

Instead of using the above, I have defined an array with a set of elements loop through it, and get the config value. But I am not able to get the config value, since fetching through a variable is not allowing. Let me know if any alternative

```
arr = ["key", "uuid", "vv"]
arr.each do |v|
  # Fetching the config value from application config
  Rails.application.config.v 
  # Or
  Rails.application.config."#{v}"
end
```

Getting an error saying - **undefined method `v' for #Rails::Application::Configuration:0x0000000152e4f360** (or) **SyntaxError ((irb):1919: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG)
...ass; Rails.application.config."#{v}"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way you may want to approach your problem is by storing your related config in a hash:

```rb
config.third_party_stuff = { 
  username: 'username',
  uuid:     'uuid',
  yyy:      'yyy'
}
```

Then you can do can pull it out all together:

```rb
third_party_config = Rails.application.config.third_party_stuff

puts "Hey #{third_party_config[:username]}, your uuid is #{third_party_config[:uuid]}"
```

If you are storing sensitive information, take a look at [rails credentials](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#custom-credentials). You can add your related information under a key in the credentials file and get the advantages above while also keeping your data safe.

Answer (score 1):

Where no other mechanism exists, you can use `Object#send` or `Object#public_send` to call a dynamic method name. For example:

```
Rails.configuration.public_send(v)
```

If another mechanism exists, like square bracket notation, `slice` method, or obtaining or converting to a hash, that may be considered preferable. I don't see an obvious one in this case.

Comment: Thanks, @matthew_tuck for the quick response. For now, I will go the dynamic method then.